# SwiftUI - I want to display birthdate(only day, month and year) after i get it out of the `Datepicker`

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

I want to display the date that user chooses using the datepicker but it displays all the information and also i want to calculate the age but i dont really know how, now i solved the problem with displaying Date() but i cant really use the code to calculate age
[image: BuildPreview]

```
    @State var firstName = ""
    @State var lastName = ""
    @State var birthdate = Date()

var dateFormatter: DateFormatter = {
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateStyle = .medium
        
        return dateFormatter
    }()
    let age = Int()
    init() {
        let age = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.year], from: birthdate, to: Date())
            .year
    }

    var body: some View {
        Form{
            Section(header: Text("Personal data")){
                TextField("Enter first name", text: $firstName)
                TextField("Enter last name", text: $lastName)
                DatePicker("Birthdate", selection: $birthdate,in: ...Date(), displayedComponents:.date)
            }
            Section(header: Text("Final info")){
                HStack{
                    Image(systemName: "person.crop.circle")
                        .resizable()
                        .frame(width: 50, height: 50, alignment: .center)
                    Spacer()
                    VStack{
                        Text("\(firstName) \(lastName)")
                            .font(.headline)
                        Text("\(birthdate)")
                            .font(.subheadline)
                    }
                    Spacer()
                    Image(systemName: "1.square.fill")
                        .resizable()
                        .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
                        .foregroundColor(.blue)
                }
                .padding(.horizontal ,10)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by displayed all information?

Comment: You can try using a `Dateformatter` to format the date the user selected

Comment: Does this your answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/67367764/14733292

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick and simple approach is to use `DateFormatter`  and luckily SwiftUI `Text` View supports it:

The code would look like this:

```
// 1. Create a Dateformatter
var dateFormatter: DateFormatter = {
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateStyle = .long
    
    return dateFormatter
}()
```

2. Change : `Text("\(birthdate)")` to `Text(birthdate, formatter:dateFormatter)`

You can play with `dateFormatter.dateStyle` value to get the one you like, check out [Set a datestyle in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24100855/set-a-datestyle-in-swift), to read more about how you can play with it

Answer (score 1):

To calculate somebody's age from their birthday, you can use code like this:

```
let age = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.year], 
                                          from: birthday, 
                                          to: Date())
.year
```

Comment: " Cannot use instance member 'birthdate' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available " i get this error can you help pls

Comment: That error is from the way you are using the code above, not the code itself. Edit your question to add the new code you are trying to use at the end.

Comment: The way you have that code written doesn't make sense. You can't just put `init()` in the middle of your date formatter like that. You need to put your code that calculates the age in response to the user picking a date in the date picker. I an not very familiar with SwiftUI so I will have to do some digging in order to provide a solution.